# Fitnesse and dbFit: unable to use variable in store query

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

```
!|DatabaseEnvironment|ORACLE|
|Connect|${HOSTNAME}|${USERNAME}|${PASSWORD}|
|set option|bind symbols|false|


!|Query|!-select acct_id ts from dual-!|
|acct_id?|
|>>acct_id|

|Set Parameter|acct_id|<<acct_id|

!|query|SELECT * from table1 where id=:acct_id|
|accr_id?|
```

getting error as below:

```
ava.lang.Error: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
at dbfit.fixture.StoreQuery.doTable(StoreQuery.java:48)
at fit.Fixture.interpretFollowingTables(Fixture.java:120)
at fit.Fixture.interpretTables(Fixture.java:106)
at fit.Fixture.doTables(Fixture.java:80)
at fit.FitServer.process(FitServer.java:81)
at fit.FitServer.run(FitServer.java:56)
at fit.FitServer.main(FitServer.java:41)
```

Is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using variables in the script using ":vaiableName" then you need to set bind symbols to true.

|set option|bind symbols|true|